# How can I call a tamper monkey function with a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that I will use as an interface.

In this interface, when the button I defined in popup.js is clicked, I want the command I want to be sent to the browser.

I will give users a tamper monkey script with the extension.

Inside this script, for example, there will be a function called myFunc().

My function will run when users type myFunc() in the browser console (if the tamper script is open).

I aim to make the browser call the function myFunc() found in my tamper script, when the button in popup.js is clicked without writing myFunc().

Is this possible, and how can I do it?

**manifest.json**

```
{
      "name": "Interface",
      "description": "Interface",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "alarms",
        "background",
        "bookmarks",
        "browserSettings",
        "browsingData",
        "captivePortal",
        "clipboardRead",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "contentSettings",
        "contextMenus",
        "contextualIdentities",
        "cookies",
        "debugger",
        "dns",
        "downloads",
        "downloads.open",
        "find",
        "geolocation",
        "history",
        "identity",
        "idle",
        "management",
        "menus",
        "menus.overrideContext",
        "nativeMessaging",
        "notifications",
        "pageCapture",
        "pkcs11",
        "privacy",
        "proxy",
        "scripting",
        "search",
        "sessions",
        "storage",
        "tabHide",
        "tabs",
        "theme",
        "topSites",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "webNavigation",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
      ],
      "action": {
        "default_title": "Interface",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "icons": {
        "16": "img/16.png",
        "32": "img/32.png",
        "48": "img/48.png",
        "128": "img/128.png"
      }
    }
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Interface</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="button-container">
      <img class="button-img" src="button-img.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**tamperMonkey**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         All functions
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    function createFolder() {
        try {
            var folderName = prompt('Folder Name');

            var jsZip = document.createElement('script');
            jsZip.type = 'text/javascript';
            jsZip.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.10.0/jszip.js';
            jsZip.className = 'jsZip';
            document.body.appendChild(jsZip);

            var fileSaver = document.createElement('script');
            fileSaver.type = 'text/javascript';
            fileSaver.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.js';
            fileSaver.className = 'fileSaver';
            document.body.appendChild(fileSaver);

            setTimeout(function () {
                var zip = new JSZip();
                zip.folder(folderName).file("myFile.js", `code code code`);

                zip.generateAsync({
                        type: "blob"
                    })
                    .then(function (content) {
                        saveAs(content, folderName);
                    });
            }, 1000);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('%c ---      ' + error + '      --- ',
                'background: black; color: white; font-size: 15px; font-family: monospace; padding: 0px;');
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please share your code. Seems like the tampermonkey script can plop the function on the window which should be easy enough for the extension to simply call as normal.

Comment: @ggorlen , I've included the codes, but I'm not so sure it will help. I have dozens of functions in my tamper file. It will be difficult to integrate these functions into the chrome extension. Therefore, I want to create an interface with the chrome extension, and call the code on the tamper monkey when the buttons are clicked.